# Content Type can't be deleted

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, content-type

I have a content type that won't go away.  I've tried messing with the feature that installed it (reinstalling, deactivating, retracting, etc.), to no avail.  Finally, here is an attempt in PowerShell that illustrates the problem succinctly:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $web = get-spweb http://cbaoth/sites/dev0
$ct = $web.ContentTypes["Timed Activity"]
$u = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentTypeUsage]::GetUsages($ct)

if ($u.Count > 0) {
  foreach ($usage in $u) {
    Write-Output ("The content type is used here: {0}",$usage)
  }
} else {
  $ct.Delete()
  $web.Update()
}
Exception calling "Delete" with "0" argument(s): "The content type "Timed Activity" is part of an application feature."
At line:10 char:13
+   $ct.Delete <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Anyone have any idea what I can do about this?  I'm developing a solution with content types in it, and I can't make changes because it fails to retract properly and the subsequent deployment fails.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check:

- This content type is not being
  references by a list or document
  library
- This content type is not
  being references by a list or
  document library that's in End User
  Recycle bin
- This content type is not
  being references by a list or
  document library that's in Site
  Collection Recycle bin
- If content
  type was deployed via feature you
  need to retract it

**Update**: The key to this is removing items from both recycle bins as clearing items from the end user recycle bin does not remove them entirely.

You still need to go to Site Settings > Recycle Bin (Under site collection administration) and then remove all items from the "Deleted from end user Recycle Bin" view.

Comment: In the code snippet I pasted, it should be obvious that `$u.Count` is 0.  The feature that originally deployed this content type has been deactivated and its solution retracted.  I also forcibly uninstalled it for good measure.

Comment: According to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms453791.aspx, the references from lists in the Recycle Bin don't count, but I emptied it anyway.

Comment: We had a similar problem and it was resolved when both Recycle bins were cleared! Hope it helps.

Comment: In my case this was a Document Set content type, and I needed to clear the 'Welcome Page Columns' before I was able to delete the content type. (Site Content Type -> Document Set Settings)